# i want to merge multiple images and videos together to create single video file by using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have tried this below thing
First i am creating video using two images like this –

```
String originalPath= “file “+”‘”+picturePath1+”‘”+”\n”+ “duration 3 \n”+”file “+”‘”+picturePath2+”‘”+”\n”+ “duration 3+”‘”+picturePath2+”‘””;  

File myFile= generateTextFile(“MyTextFile”,originalPath); // here i convert into text file
```

After that executing command,

```
String command[] = {“-y”, “-f”, “concat”, “-safe”, “0”, “-i”,myFile.getAbsolutePath(), “-vsync”, “vfr”, “-pix_fmt”, “yuv420p”, VideoSavePath};
```

Able to create video and using the created video path (VideoSavePath ) in below command

```
String mutipleVideo[] = {“-y”, “-i”, firstVideoPath, “-i”,secondVideoPath , “-i”, VideoSavePath, “-filter_complex”,
“[0:v]scale=480×640,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=480×640,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]scale=480×640,setsar=1[v2];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1”,
“-ab”, “48000”, “-ac”, “2”, “-ar”, “22050”, “-s”, “480×640”, “-vcodec”, “libx264″,”-crf”,”27″,”-preset”, “ultrafast”, newFinalVideoPath};
```

but i am getting error(matches no streams) while using videopath getting from first command and this second command is working fine if i am using some random videopath in place of VideoSavePath

Comment: You need to narrow down the issue. Is the problem with your code or your `ffmpeg` command or both? Try running `ffmpeg` manually, unscripted using the same command that the code implements, and include the resulting log.

Comment: getting issues in my second command mutipleVideo[] whenever i used created videopath from images .